# Group similar error messages - NLP/machine learning python

Tags: python, nlp, classification

I have close to 500 error messages in an excel file which I am trying to group similar error messages. Following are some of the sample error messages.

1. Invalid account name
2. Invalid account number
3. Date closed is before open date
4. End date is before active date
5. Account Name must be unique
6. Account number must be unique

My requirement is to group (or) classify similar error messages to groups.

One way which I attempted so far is use Doc2Vec to generate vectors after doing pre processing on text. But I am not sure how to proceed with the vectors and how to group using the vector output.

Can someone suggest how to proceed further on this? If there is any other better way to do. Please suggest.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question, you have vectors of your data but you have no labels, right? if you have no labels, I do not believe if classification makes any sense. You should go with clustering.  If you can estimate your group numbers ( cluster number), you can try a **Kmeans** to see how it goes. If you do not know the number of clusters, use a **bottom-up clustering** or **DBSCAN**

Comment: Yes.. I do not have labels.. I did DBSCAN.. But I am not sure how to make sense of the output.. are there any similar tutorials or sample code for DBSCAN?

Comment: Normally you should look at the data, at the clusters, and see if it resolves your problem and is actually doing your task. Depends if you have clearly defined the task, and you know what you want at the end.  If you did so, looking at the results,  can help. For DBSCAN, they are plenty of examples on the web. Here is one of the random ones i found via google: https://medium.com/@elutins/dbscan-what-is-it-when-to-use-it-how-to-use-it-8bd506293818